# Should I use validation.yml or Assertions in the Class?

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have a question about best practice. I noticed that for form validation Symfony allows me to either use Acme\Bundle\Resource\config\validation.yml as shown below to validate:

```
Acme\Bundle\Entity\School
    properties:
       zipCode:
            - MinLength: 5
```

Or I can also use Assertions in the class itself. So in Acme\Bundle\Entity\School.php it would look like this:

```
...
class School
{
 ...
 /**
  * @Assert\MinLength(limit="5", message="Zipcode too short")
  */
 protected $zipCode;
 ...
}
```

Which one is better practice? or is it just preference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's completely up to you, that's why they provide many different ways.

Don't forget that a single bundle can only use one type.

Answer (score 2):

While Jessica is correct that both methods are best practice, I find using `@Assert` to be much more convenient as it keeps all the entity related data in the entity.

Since I don't need to look up a second file (a daunting task!), it is easier when I need to change or consult that information later on.

In YML's favor though, it is much cleaner and easier to read than annotations.

Comment: Thanks! I decided to use @assert since splitting the validation.yml file into separate files would take more work. I'm glad my reasoning matches someones else's.

Comment: Personally I'm still torn. I liked yml at first for it's easy of reading, but then switched to Annotation because it was easier to edit on the fly as I built my application. Try one and then try the other. :)